# Type for RouteTree (Recursive types)

Tags: typescript

I want to write some types for an object that will hold data like follows:

```js
const routes = {
    '/test': {
      name: 'a',
      '/a': {
        name: 'a',
        '/b': {
          name: 'Yes',
        },
      },
    },
    '/test2': {
      name: 'a',
      '/a': {
        name: 'a',
        '/b': {
          name: 'Yes',
        },
      },
    }
}
```

I have tried with some options and this is currently working for me:

```js
interface RouteTree {
  [path: string]: PageRoute;
}

interface PageRoute {
  name: string;
  [path: string]: PageRoute | string | undefined;
}
```

However, I don't feel like that is the best solution. There is also two problems I have find:

- The name property is in some way being included inside [path: string]
- If I needed to add a new non-string property for the PageRoute I think it would break my typing

I'm just looking how to improve the typing.

Comment: Do the paths always start with `"/"` and none of the non-path properties begin with `"/"`?  Then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAJJvW) might meet your needs.  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; let me know.

Comment: Yeah, all paths will always start with "/" and non-path will not begin with it. I take look at the approach you provided and I think that's exactly what I want. @jcalz